# google maps api polygon to polygon instead of point to polygon collision

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

There's a method for polygon detection called:
containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)

However, this checks if a point (single co-ordinate) is inside a polygon, but I need it to check if a polygon is inside of another polygon.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check if your polygon contains all the points of the other?

Comment: What if there's two giant rectangle polygons that intersect each other but none of the points are inside of the polygon?

Here's an image, maybe that'll help?

http://imgur.com/a/trTLK

Ignore the red ones, I'm on about the blue ones.

Comment: Then it won't work.   I'm sure there is GIS software somewhere that will solve your problem.

Comment: Is there a way to convert a polygon into lots of points? Say a polygon spanning 10 lat and 10 lng, converting that into points would give you something like 100 horizontal points, and 100 vertical points?

Comment: Sure. Use [interpolate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) on the line segments

Answer (score 0):

Basically what @geocodezip says.  You don't give any clue about how you're creating your polygons, so you maybe don't need to find out all the points like this.  But it should work regardless.

I get all the paths of the polygon you want to check.  Then loop over those paths, getting all the points and adding them to an array.  Then loop over that array, checking if each point falls within the other polygon.

```
var paths = polygon1.getPaths();
var points = [];

paths.forEach(function(path) {
    path.forEach(function(point) {
        points.push(point);
    });
});

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    if (!google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(points[i], polygon2)) {
        alert('this point is not in the other polygon: ' + points[i].toString());
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there's two giant rectangle polygons that intersect each other but none of the points are inside of the polygon? Here's an image, maybe that'll help? http://imgur.com/a/trTLK Ignore the red ones, I'm on about the blue ones.